# How to rebuild net/http library

Tags: go

for debug purpose, I'd like to re-compile with some of my own traces the net/http library.

To give it a first try I'm using a very simple go program that makes a GET HTTP requests and print the response body

- I'm using Go 1.13 on a CentOS virtual machine
- I've got my app in $GOPATH/src/myapp
- I've cloned the  net/http package in $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/net using: `git clone -b release-branch.go1.13 https://github.com/golang/net.git`

Now I'm struggling to find the command to re-generate the net.a lib and link it to my application, any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Please note that I do not have write access to /usr/local/go which is my $GOROOT.

Comment: "I've cloned the net/http package" This is wrong. It simply doesn't  work like that. You **cannot** clone Go packages (in general) and it is **absolutely** **impossible** to use your own variant  of a stdlib package. If you want to use a modified stdlib package you must modifiy the stdlib in place (in which case recompilation should happen automatically).

Comment: "Please note that I do not have write access to /usr/local/go which is my $GOROOT" In which case you simply cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: And please stop using Go 1.13 and GOPATH builds. Its late 2020.

Comment: [Install Go](https://golang.org/doc/install#install) somewhere in your HOME directory (but not $HOME/go) and, as Volker said, modify the standard library in place. Use `go env GOROOT` to verify that you're using your local installation instead of the one in /usr/local/go.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answers. @Volker, I guess with my question you might have figured out I'm a newby on go, so sorry if I'm not understanding why "stop using GOPATH".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a simple tracer, you can just add middleware or a chain of them for every event in the request chain. If you want to `re-package` golang with your own stdlib, i'm afraid that is not possible.

If you want to contribute to golang proper you can follow the contributing guide here [contribution guide](https://golang.org/doc/contribute.html).

Comment: Thx alexad, it's what I've started to do in the mean time downloading the go source code.

Comment: thx again, the Go contribution guide is really well done. Did recompile the version of go originally used to build the software I was trying to debug and by adding some new traces in go net & crypto packages, I could pin-point the root cause of the problem.